# Find an Input word in a text and print the "associated Character"

Tags: python

I have to do a program that find a word in a text and then print another word (or character) associated to it. For example, text file is :

"
-POST- 1

blablabla abcde

-POST-   15

wordwordword helloworld "

If input is "blablabla" or "abcde" output should be "1" ( the post'ID'),
if input is wordwordword or "Helloworld" output should be "15".

My idea is to create a dictionary d={'ID':'word'} to categorize the posts, but can't do more than this:

```
def post(fposts,insieme):
l=list(insieme)


d={}
with open(fposts) as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for i in line.split():
            if i=='<POST>':
                for j in l:
                    if j in i:
                        d={i+1:j}

    return d
```

"Fposts" is the directory of the file
can you help me? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly clear what you want but i gave a try using regex here you go :

```
import re

def print_id(string):
    pattern="""([0-9]).*\s+([match_word].+)"""
    pattern2=r'\bmatch_word\b'

    replace1=re.sub(pattern2,string,pattern)
    new_dict={}
    with open('po.txt') as f:
        read_file=f.read()
        match=re.search(replace1,read_file,re.M)
        new_dict[string]=match.group(1)

    return new_dict
```

First test with `blablabla`

```
print(print_id("blablabla"))
```

output:

```
{'blablabla': '1'}
```

second test with `wordwordword`

```
print(print_id("wordwordword"))
```

output:

```
{'wordwordword': '15'}
```

Comment: thanks for all ! only one question : what means "pattern" and "pattern2"?

Comment: @SimonePaolo those are regular expression pattern. If my solution worked for you, Please accept the answer.

Comment: @SimonePaolo you don't need to insert anything there , just give string as argument in function and change the filename there.

Comment: i do that, but it doesnt't work, for example if insert a string , program doesn't associate it to the right "id"

Comment: @SimonePaolo i tried with your test strings and it worked for both , Now i don't have idea what is your actual file format how many spaces etc , what you provided i tried with that data.